# Confusion with sscanf_s

Tags: c

I am having issues with sscanf_s, essentially I have this line of code:

```
sscanf_s( line.c_str(),
          "<float_array id=\"%*s[^\"]\" count=\"%*d\">%[^<]s",
          numString);
```

I am feeding it this line of text:

```
<float_array id="Cube-mesh-positions-array" count="24">1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -0.9999998 -1    -0.9999997 1 -1 1 0.9999995 1 0.9999994 -1.000001 1 -1 -0.9999997 1 -1 1 1</float_array>
```

What I am trying to achieve is read the number array written after `count="24">` and pass it to another function, however `numString` remains with a value of `""` after being passed through the equation, therefore causing the subsequent functions to fail. if anyone could offer me insight into why this is occurring I would be very appreciative.

A short SSCCE that I have tested has revealed that the problem lies elsewhere, I shall have to investigate this further - sorry for wasting your time, and thank you for taking your time to try and help me.

Comment: What type is `numString` ? can you give an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) ? note that sscanf_s is C and thus your question might be better reformulated as a C question, unless some C++ specific thing is part of the question.

Comment: numString is just a string variable (using std::string), and my apologies about the mismark as a C++ question, I was using C++ and have no experience in C and so was not aware that this was a C function

Comment: Note that the `s` at the end of the format string is a literal `s`, not part of the scan-set notation.  Fortunately for you, there's no way to tell that it fails to match in the input string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `sscanf_s` is a Microsoft invention, intended to be "more secure" than the standard `sscanf` function.

As such, if you are using `"%s"` or `"%c"`, it requires **two** parameters: One being the buffer to write the input to, and *an integer specifying the available size of the buffer*, so that a long input string does not result in a buffer overflow.

Unfortunately this is not quite that obvious to users of the function (like yourself), resulting in frequent mis-use of the function (which somewhat reduces the "security" implied).

[Link to the Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/t6z7bya3.aspx); refer to the section "remarks".

So what you have here is undefined behaviour, as `sscanf_s` attempts to read an integer from the stack where you haven't put one. You end up lucky that the memory read is apparently zero, so zero bytes are written to `numString`.

This should do nicely:

```
size_t BUFSIZE = 50;
char numString[ BUFSIZE ];
sscanf_s( line.c_str(),
          "<float_array id=\"%*s[^\"]\" count=\"%*d\">%[^<]s",
          numString, BUFSIZE );
```

---

Note that `numString` better actually *be* a `char[]`. Your question was initially tagged as C++; if `numString` is actually a `std::string`, be advised that you cannot use the `scanf` family function with `std::string` parameters.

---

(Sorry for the edits, got it wrong the first few times. That format string is something... ;-) )

Comment: Minor: "if you are using `"%s"` or `"%c"`" should also include `"%["`.

Comment: @chux: Actually it's "type field characters c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []." I've never had use for [] myself, so I wrongly assumed that the specifier is actually `"%[]s"`. Which raises another point with the OP's code: The trailing `"s"` is erroneous.

Comment: True that format better as `"<float_array id=\"%*[^\"]\" count=\"%*d\">%[^<]",` (drop _2_ s).  `C` ans `S` are MS extensions.  `sscanf_s` is in the C spec in the appendix.

Comment: I tried the edits you suggested (using much larger numbers, as this system is supposed to work for long strings as well as short) and am still coming across the same problem, except now `numString` is equal to `"ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..."` after the function fires

Comment: @user2289437: An update of your question including a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would be nice.

Comment: added as close to an SSCCE as I could manage, sorry if I screwed it up

Comment: @user2289437: No, that's not what "short" means. "Short" would be one line defining the string to be scanned, one line scanning the string, one line printing what was scanned. If your problem really is with `sscanf_s`, those three lines would suffice, and all the remaining code is superfluous. If your problem is *not* with `sscanf_s` (let's say, you've got an error in your reading-from-file), you would find out while reducing the code. You know, right now I'm sitting on my terrace, enjoying the sunshine at 33 degree celsius. If you want me to give an answer, make the question easy. ;-)

Comment: this means if you use sscanf_s in accordance with %f, you don't need to specify any buffersizes since 'float' has a fixed size, correct?

Comment: @AgentM: As the linked docs state, *"...a buffer size parameter is required when you use the type field characters c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []."* -- As %f is not mentioned here, no buffer size parameter is expected.

Comment: How could sscanf_s be used insecurely?

Answer (score 1):

```
char numString[ 256 ];
sscanf_s( line.c_str(),
          "<float_array id=\"%*[^\"]\" count=\"%*d\">%255[^<]",
          numString, 256);
```

Comment: Maybe explain a bit more.

Comment: There is an extra `s` in the code of the OP. OP also need to specify the buffer size.